# How can I prevent Garageband from removing downloaded sound library installation files after installation?

Tags: high-sierra, macos, garageband

Garageband will download full sound library when requested, install them, and then delete the installation file/package. Sometimes, I want to be able to install those again without having to download them from the internet again (for example, if I deleted the sound library due to lack of space in the boot drive, but I need it again sometime afterwards).

However, it seems like there is no documented or easy ways to prevent the deletion. One possible solution might be watching the temporary directory and hard-linking every file that appeared, but I don't know of a software/script that will do it.

So how can I keep the downloaded installation packages and install them to Garageband again later in case where I deleted the sound library and don't want to download from the internet again?

The directory Garageband use to store the downloaded installation files is `/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.MusicApps/audiocontentdownload.apple.com`. I'm thinking of using fs_usage to get what files are created and hard-link them to another directory, but I don't know how to do that using a script.

Comment: This highly depends on the application (and the method it uses in this case). It also assumes that the application is even able to load the additional data from a file (instead of an URL). So please focus your question on a specific application.

Comment: Isn't this what a backup is for?